# Why implicit conversion doesn't work in Lists?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Could someone give a quick explanation why implicit conversion doesn't work in these cases? Thanks.

```
scala> implicit def strTwoInt (s: String):Int = s.toCharArray.map{_.asDigit}.sum
strTwoInt: (s: String)Int

scala> List[Int]("1","2","3") sum
res3: Int = 6

scala> List("1","2","3") sum
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[java.lang.String]
        List("1","2","3") sum

scala> val a = List("1","2","3")                          
scala> a.foldLeft(0)((i:Int, j:Int) => i+j)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: (Int, java.lang.String) => Int
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, in what you want to do the the `sum` in your implicit conversion and with the `sum` after `List[Int]("1","2","3")`?

Comment: @Lutz you mean the `sum` of the form `def sum [B >: A] (implicit num: Numeric[B]): B `? Maybe, but I don't understand how that works

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear enough. What would be your *expected* results of your examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implicit conversion converts a String in an Int. In your first example, it is triggered by the fact that you try to put Strings into a List of Ints.

In your second example, you have a List of String and you call the method sum, which takes an implicit `Numeric[String]`. Your conversion does not apply because you neither try to pass a String somewhere the compiler was expecting an Int, nor you tried to call a method which is defined in Int and not in String. In that case, you can either define a `Numeric[String]` which use *explicitly* your conversion, or use a method which takes a `List[Int]` as parameter (giving hint to the compiler):

```
scala> def sumIt( xs: List[Int] ) = xs sum
sumIt: (xs: List[Int])Int

scala> sumIt( List("1","2","3") )
res5: Int = 6
```

In the third example, the foldLeft second argument must be of type:

```
(Int,String) => Int
```

the one you actually passed is of type:

```
(Int,Int) => Int
```

however, you did not define any implicit conversion between these two types. But:

```
a.foldLeft(0)((i:Int, j:String) => i+j)
```

triggers your conversion and works.

**Edit:** Here's how to implement the `Numeric[String]`:

```
implicit object StringNumeric extends math.Numeric[String] {
  val num = math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral
  def plus(x: String, y: String) = num.plus(x,y).toString
  def minus(x: String, y: String) = num.minus(x,y).toString
  def times(x: String, y: String) = num.times(x,y).toString
  def negate(x: String): String = num.negate(x).toString
  def fromInt(x: Int) = x.toString
  def toInt(x: String) = x
  def toLong(x: String) = toInt(x)
  def toFloat(x: String) = toInt(x)
  def toDouble(x: String) = toInt(x)
  def compare(x:String,y:String) = num.compare(x,y)
}

scala> List("1","2","3") sum
res1: java.lang.String = 6
```

It works, but the result is a String.

Comment: As does simply `a.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)` ... I think I only put the types in because I was trying to get it to work with `reduceLeft`. Do you think you could expand on what defining a Numeric[String] would involve?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick explanation: implicit conversions apply to the types the convert from and to directly (e.g., `String` and `Int` in your case), and not to any parametrized type `T[String]` or `T[Int]` — unless implicit conversions have been defined for `T` itself, and it is not the case for lists.

Your implicit conversion does not apply in your two cases (and even if you had an implicit conversion from `List[String]` to `List[Int]`, it wouldn't apply). It would automatically applied only when you need a value of type `Int` and you're passing `String` instead. Here, in the first case, the method `sum` asks for a `Numeric[String]` implicit parameter — an implicit conversion from `String` to `Int` does not come into play here.

Similar problem for your next attempt: the `foldLeft` on your collection requires a function of type `(Int, String) => Int`. Imagine the mess we would get into if, based on an implicit conversion from `String` to `Int`, the compiler automatically provided an implicit conversion from `(Int, Int) => Int` to `(Int, String) => Int`…

For all these cases, the easy way to fix it is to explicitly call `.map(stringToInt)` on your collection beforehand.